# What is the 'on quit' handler used for?

Tags: applescript, handler

I know all of the basic handlers, i.e. `on run`, `on open`, and `on reopen`. But this handler, `on quit`, confuses me. My questions are, what is it used for and how is it triggered?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`on quit` is used in scripts that have been saved as a standalone application. The user can quit such a script using its menus. A `quit` handler runs when the user quits the script, and can put up a confirmation dialog asking if they are sure they really want to quit, or clean up any temporary files it created, etc. -- anything the script needs to do before it ends. When you have finished doing whatever it is you want to do, `continue quit` to actually allow the script to exit.

Often used with an `on idle` handler, as scripts with such a handler can stay open for long periods of time and the user may need some way to exit them.

Answer (score 3):

`on quit` is a function that allows you to do something on quit. To trigger it, simply use `quit`. For example, if I wanted to say to the user "Thanks for trying this!" then I'd do this:

```
--lots of code, blah blah
quit

on quit
display dialog "Thanks for trying this!" buttons {"Continue"}
continue quit
end
```

Which would display a dialog, then it would continue quitting. But, if I wanted to cancel quit, I'd remove the `continue quit` line.

Hopefully this should make sense.

Comment: Thanks, and yes, it does make sense! I wish I could accept more than one answer, though. :(